# rocon: 'already connected to this hub'

Tags: ros, rocon

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am following through the [roscon installation tutorial for ROS Hydro](http://wiki.ros.org/rocon/Tutorials/hydro/Installation), but I am getting stuck at the verification step.

The instructions say to execute:

```
> . /opt/ros/hydro/setup.bash
> rocon_launch chatter_concert chatter.concert
```

When I do this the terminal windows spawn as expected. However they all have a warning:

```
[WARN] [WallTime: 1409023936.036277] Gateway : not registering on the hub [already connected to this hub]
[WARN] [WallTime: 1409023936.544642] Gateway : not registering on the hub [already connected to this hub]
```

**Is this warning a problem or not?** The hub seems to be running as though it's a daemon, as closing the terminal down and starting this command again does not make the warning go away.

I would post a screen shot but I don't have enough points (need at least 20) to do so.

Kind Regards
Bart

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/191234/rocon:-%27already-connected-to-this-hub%27/) by [bjem85](https://answers.ros.org/users/18596/bjem85/) on ROS Answers with karma: 163 on 2014-08-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2014-08-27**:
I don't know about this message in particular, but warnings generally imply that a given operation worked, although something was noticed in passing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ok, digging back through my memory, I believe this is because it was starting a gateway with default settings to look for a hub on localhost, and also via zeroconf. If the localhost hub was found (which it did for chatter_concert), then zeroconf discovery would throw this warning when it would discover the same hub.

This has been updated on the hydro-devel/indigo branches so that it doesn't do this double lookup.

In short, don't worry about it :)

---

Originally posted by [Daniel Stonier](https://answers.ros.org/users/51/daniel-stonier/) with karma: 3170 on 2014-09-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bjem85](https://answers.ros.org/users/18596/bjem85/) on 2014-09-16**:
I haven't verified this but it sounds reasonable.